# NPM install grunt@version - No repository field

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to install grunt since the `grunt watch` for example is not working, shows as error: `grunt command not found`. When I do `npm install grunt@0.4.1 --save-dev` this is what appears:

[image]

And does not let me install it. I tried doing another package.json, doing a clean `npm install` and still, no idea what's going on.

Can anyone help me please, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you installed the grunt CLI? `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: Post this as the answer please. I swear I just finished one project and had to move to the next one. Been on this for countless hours now. This is so obvious and yet I totally forgot to get the CLI going.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't have it installed globally initially :)

Comment: This is a different computer, so yes, probably I didn't have it installed globally. T-T

Comment: Are you going to accept the answer, since it solved your issue? :-)

Comment: My bad! I was going to and it told I needed to wait 3min, they I totally forgot. There

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to install the Grunt CLI globally:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

With this in place you should be able to setup grunt for any new project.